# Find most-frequently-occurring element with O(n) time and O(1) space

Tags: python, algorithm

I want to find the most-frequently-occurring element in a list, in `O(n)` time and `O(1)` space.

**First Solution**

```
from collections import Counter
def max_repetitions(elements):
    return max([v for k, v in Counter(elements).items() if v > 1])
```

Space complexity is `O(n)`. I'm not sure about time complexity. Is it `O(nlogn)` or `O(n)`?

**Second solution**

```
def max_repetitions(elements):
counter = 0
for k, v in Counter(elements).items():
    if v > 1 and counter < v:
        counter = k
return counter
```

What is the time-complexity of this solution? Is it `O(nlogn)` or `O(n)`?

Is there any other way?

Comment: Both of these look like O(n) space complexity in the worst case. If your initial list equals `range(1000)`, then your Counter will take up 1000 slots. (Yes, it still counts as occupying space even if you never give it a variable name)

Comment: They should both have time complexity of O(n).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In simple cases like these: To get the time complexity try to answer how many times you iterate over the elements in a sequence.

Since you're using the `Counter` class in the `collections` module that will also affect the complexity, but let's assume that it's O(n).

The only other work you do is to iterate over the list again, with also is O(n). That gives O(n) as the time complexity, as it grows linearly with the number of elements `n`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a majority element, which is an element that appears more than `n/2` times in the array, you can use the (very simple) MJRTY algorithm due to Boyer-Moore: http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~moore/best-ideas/mjrty/
This runs in `O(n)` time with `O(1)` space.

Answer (score 0):

If your list is already sorted

```
function maxItem(list) {
var maxCount = 0;
var maxElement = null;
for(var i = 0, count = 1, elm = null; i < list.length; i++) {
  if(elm != list[i]) {
    count = 1;
    elm = list[i];
  } else { 
    count++;
  }
  if(count > maxCount) {
    maxCount = count;
    maxElement = elm;
  }
}
return maxElement;
}

console.log(maxItem([1,1,1, 2,2,2,2, 4,4, 8,8,8,8,8])); // 8
console.log(maxItem([1,1,1, 2,2,2,2, 4,4, 8,8,8,8,8, 9])); // 8
console.log(maxItem([8])); // 8
```

**edit** sorry it's JavaScript not python